# Change/add infobox display count in osCommerce 

Tags: oscommerce

I'm modifying an osCommerce site (started by someone else) and on the homepage, there's a box (called infobox I believe, or new_products box). It's currently showing nine (9) products, and I want to change it to show six (6).

How can I do this? Is it a code thing or something I can change through the admin section?

Is it also possible to add a second infobox showing six (6) products from another category?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm modifying an osCommerce site
>   (started by someone else) and on the
>   homepage, there's a box (called
>   infobox I believe, or new_products
>   box). It's currently showing nine (9)
>   products, and I want to change it to
>   show six (6).
>
> How can I do this? Is it a code thing
>   or something I can change through the
>   admin section?

The setting is in the Admin section: Configuration -> Maximum Values -> New Products Module.